# converts an abnormal character into a normal character (e.g., an unicode character) in python

Tags: python, non-ascii-characters, unicode-string

How to converts an abnormal character into a normal character (e.g., an unicode character), In other words, decoding an abnormal characters/string  like 'Ã¢Â€Â' to reveal its contents?

```
context='This Service does not use these Ã¢Â€ÂœcookiesÃ¢Â€Â explicitly. However, the app may'
context1= context.encode('utf8') # encode('ascii')
print(context1)
```

Output:

```
 b'This Service does not use these \xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\x82\xc2\x80\xc3\x82\xc2\x9ccookies\xc3\x83\xc2\xa2\xc3\x82\xc2\x80\xc3\x82\xc2\x9d explicitly. However, the app may'
```

I would like to print the string without these characters (Ã¢Â€Â)

Comment: So a regular `print(context)`, printing the characters as is, is not wanted or did not work. What should happen to the non-ASCII characters ?  Should they be excluded from print-out or transformed to their ASCII-equivalent - [unicode normalization](https://dencode.com/en/string/unicode-normalization) ?

Comment: What do you mean by "normal" or "abnormal" characters ?  Are these _non-ASCII_ characters like `Ã¢Â€Âœ` abnormal ... is a "€" (currency-symbol for EUR) normal ?

Comment: This looks like mojibake - text that has been encoded with multiple encodings.  How did you obtain this string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, You can try this..You can use encode to ASCII if you don't need to translate the non-ASCII characters:

```
content.encode('ascii','ignore')
```

#output

```
This Service does not use these cookies explicitly. However, the app may'
```

Comment: Nice solution. Not sure it is what they asked for. Can you add some links and explain: e.g. what the [module `unicodedata`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html) and method `normalize` with "NFKD" does to our string, and why do we need the encode-to-ASCII.

Comment: @Bhargav thanks for your solution. It is a good solution but it is not the optimal solution that i want. is there way to delete  'AAA' from string which is resulting from  the Unicode lib for Ã¢ÂÂ.

Comment: I need the output to be like 'This Service does not use these cookies explicitly. However, the app may'

Comment: Check edited reply :)..Isn't that simple?

Comment: Deos it worked?